# Question about randomstate usage in an svc example

Tags: python, scikit-learn

In the [first lines of code of this example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#computing-cross-validated-metrics)
can someone explain the use of `random_state` in the line:

```py
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1, random_state=42)
```

I am new in scikit-learn and I do not understand the usage of `random_state` since `probability=False` by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in [the SVC documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html):

> `random_state`: Controls the pseudo random number generation for shuffling the data for probability estimates. Ignored when `probability` is False. Pass an int for reproducible output across multiple function calls.

So in this particular case: `random_state=42` does not change the behavior, but neither does it *hurt* performance.

It is helpful to have reproducible results when sharing/writing documentation. Therefore, it's often good to be in the habit of adding `random_state=[something]`, even in cases when it is not strictly needed.